# jQuery hasClass check on altered DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble with the jQuery function 'hasClass'. It returns false while it should return true. The hasClass function is looking for an class which was added by javascript. So maybe the hasClass function can't find classes in altered HTML? If so, how can I fix it the best way?

```
$(".slides").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"width": "+=30px", "height": "+=30px", "margin-top": "+=15px"}, 200);
})

$(".slides").mouseout(function(){
    alert($(this).hasClass('activeSlide'));
    if(!$(this).hasClass('activeSlide')){
        $(this).stop(true, true).animate({"width": "-=30px", "height": "-=30px", "margin-top": "-=15px"}, 200);
    }
});

$("body").click(function(){
    $(".activeSlide").removeClass("activeSlide");   
});

$(".slides").click(function(){
    $(".activeSlide").removeClass("activeSlide");
    $(this).addClass("activeSlide");
    alert("Set");
});
```

Comment: If you are going to use the same selector multiple times in the same scope, you really should cache the JQ selector into a variable and use it. `var foo = jQuery(this);`

Answer (score 5):

Because of event propagation you your body click handler is always removing the activeSlide class.

try [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/);

```
$(".slides").click(function(event){
    $(".activeSlide").removeClass("activeSlide");
    $(this).addClass("activeSlide");
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert("Set");
});
```

or

```
$(".slides").click(function(){
    $(".activeSlide").removeClass("activeSlide");
    $(this).addClass("activeSlide");
    alert("Set");
    return false;
});
```